# how to reference class name of extended class from the base class (this.constractor.name) in CoffeeScript or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

i have simple inheritance. Once initiated, i can find out what class it is by looking up the constructor name:

```
someClass = new SomeClass()
console.log someClass.constructor.name //SomeClass
base = new Base()
console.log base.constructor.name //Base
```

I would like to access the name of the Class of the current object in the Base class in the save() method for example:

```
class Base
  constructor: (obj) ->
    ...
  save: (fn) ->
   @constructor.name
```

As you see, i am trying to do so via '@constructor.name', but this is not working. In short, i would like to reference the name of an the extended class from the base class. How to do so? Thank You

Comment: May be helpful: http://coffeescript.org/#classes

Comment: What you have does work (except for the missing parentheses on console.log. http://jsfiddle.net/bYUwM/

Comment: Maybe you're calling `save` when it's not bound to an instance of `Base`? Try replacing `save: (fn) ->` with `save: (fn) =>`, and see if that fixes it. Also try `console.log this` in your `save` function to see what `this` actually is at the time you call the function.

Comment: You've done it right, and it works... What's the issue?

Comment: Thank You all. My mistake was forgetting multiple scopes that i didn't in include in the sample code when posting the question. more details in my comment under Paul's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making a couple changes to the example code [**here**](http://coffeescript.org/#classes), I came up with this

```
class Shape
  constructor: () ->

  type: () ->
    console.log @constructor.name

class Square extends Shape

class Circle extends Shape

sq = new Square
ci = new Circle

sq.type() // Square
ci.type() // Circle
```

---

**Edit:** If you wanted to get the name `Shape` when using the class `Square` or `Circle` (i.e. the name of the class from which the invoking class was extended) then it would be

```
console.log @constructor.__super__.constructor.name
```

It looks horrible, but I'm not sure if there is an easier way. It may cause an exception if the class isn't the result of an `extends`.

I realised you can follow this path when I saw in the generated *JavaScript*

```
function Square() {
    _ref = Square.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    return _ref;
}
```

Comment: Thank You Paul. my mistake in multiple scopes. In my save method, i had http.request scope within which another scope of redis.hashCommand. So when referencing by @constructor.name, then it was referencing the wrong scope. So by doing first 'self = @' and then in the other scope 'self.constructor.name' was the solution